# How to change image on mouse hover

Tags: html, mouseover

I am a beginner. I am working on this webpage
[salesletter](https://tryslimleaf.com/d24/indexwritten.php). I am trying to change the button color of the add-to-cart buttons by changing their image on mouseover. [image] I am unable to do so with though with my limited knowledge and google isn't able to help me this time. I'd like to ask for your help on how I am going to be able to do this. I tried some codes that I found on google but they dont work. I have no knowledge of JS btw. Thanks!

Update: thanks for the help of Jan Kees, I was able to accomplish the goal however, there is a problem. here is my current code:

```css
.add-2-cart {
  max-width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 0%;
  padding-right: 0%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px;
}

.add-2-cart:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="add-2-cart col-flex-fullwidth">
  <a href="https://www.digistore24.com/product/394232" target="_blank">
    <img src='images/a2c-1btl-am.png' onmouseover="this.src='images/a2c-1btl-amh.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/a2c-1btl-am.png'" class="fluid-img">
  </a>
</div>
```

Now the problem is the image change does not immediately take effect. I need to hover multiple times on the image before it actually works properly.

Answer (score 0):

That's using the adjacent sibling combinator (`+`).

```css
.image {
  height: 100px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px;
  background: orange;
  width: 50px;
}

.image:hover+.btn {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://www.vectorlogo.zone/logos/stackoverflow/stackoverflow-tile.svg">
  <div class="btn">button</div>
</img>
```

**OR**

if the whole card is an image you can change the content in the css.

```css
img {
  height: 150px;
}

img:hover {
  content: url("https://tryslimleaf.com/d24/images/a2c-6btl-amh.png");
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://tryslimleaf.com/d24/images/a2c-6btl-am.png">
```